# Disable mouse wheel only works if page is scrolled to top

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to disable the mouse wheel for my page. This works if the page is scrolled all the way to the top when this function is called. If I scroll down any length and then call the function again, the function fails. What could cause this?

**UPDATE** - I figured out what the issue was. It had to do with some CSS settings for the scrollable element in the background. I had to change the position property from absolute to relative, and now no more scrolling!

```
$(document).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function () {
    return false
});
```

Comment: Why are you disabling the scroll wheel?

Comment: I am developing a node webkit app, and I would like to disable to scroll wheel for a modal that I am displaying.

Comment: Can't you just use overflow: hidden?

Comment: When I set overflow hidden, the scollable content behind the modal disappears.

Comment: what browser you're testing it on?

Comment: Within my node webkit app, but also test on the latest chrome build which shows the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false
});
```

Comment: No change unfortunately.

Comment: In that case I think we need to see more code. Can you duplicate your issue in a [codepen](http://codepen.io)?